# Conditional Formatting several lists

Tags: excel, formatting

I have is a calendar at the top and a series of columns below.  If a date is input in the columns below I want the calendar automatically to change colour to match.

Is this possible without matching each individual cell?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the day numbers are actually dates formatted as dd you can apply a conditional format on the whole range with the formula. The relative reference will do the rest.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(D5,$C$19:$C$100,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to check a whole 2D range, you would need something like

```
=SUM(--(D5=$C$19:$P$100))
```

But if you wanted different colours for different columns, you'd have to do a separate rule with a separate lookup on each column.

If they are *not* dates but just numbers, you'd need to make them into dates:-

```
=SUM(--(DATE(2016,ROWS(D$5:D5),D5)=$C$19:$P$100))
```